# Azure: 409 Conflict: Cannot delete directory. It is either not empty or access is not allowed

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I use Azure with node js App Service. 
When i try to delete empty folder using ftp or kudu app in node_modules folders i get error: **409 Conflict: Cannot delete directory. It is either not empty or access is not allowed**. This folder is totally empty. How i can delete it?

Comment: Have you tried suggested solution of this issue from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/805a4b90-963b-4ff2-ad15-218e496e9a9c/cant-remove-a-folder-in-azure-app-service?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview ?

Comment: yes and it not works

Answer (score 21):

Check AppSettings of Web App and delete the setting ‘WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE’ or changing the setting value to 0.

0 - write mode;
1 - read-only mode

Answer (score 3):

There is a Process explorer tab in the header.

1. Open Process explorer
2. Kill the task that's using the folder or file
3. You will be able to delete the folder in question

This is how I resolved the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution: adding this option to your step deploying to the app service.
Hope it would help

[image: Options for deploying]

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [command](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#command) api to do that. Craft a CMD or PowerShell command that'll clean your wwwroot and then execute it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the upper solutions and didn't worked. Blackhole!
I stopped the app service, removed the files and started again. It worked.